# Keyboard hooking only works on 32-bit programs

Tags: c++, windows, hook

./index.cpp

```
#include <functional> // std::function
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Keyboard_hook/index.h"

int main () {
    HMODULE DLL_handle = LoadLibraryA("Keyboard_hook/index.dll");
    std::function<Hook_interface *()> get_hook = reinterpret_cast<Hook_interface *(*)()>(GetProcAddress(DLL_handle, "get_hook"));
    Hook_interface *hook = get_hook();

    hook->start_hooking();

    system("pause");

    hook->stop_hooking();
    FreeLibrary(DLL_handle);
    return 0;
}
```

./Keyboard_hook/index.dll

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <Windows.h>
#include "index.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc (int n_code, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param);

namespace global {
    HINSTANCE instance_handle;
}

class Hook : public Hook_interface {
    private:
        static HHOOK hook_handle;

    public:
        static HHOOK get_hook_handle () {
            return Hook::hook_handle;
        }

        void start_hooking () {
            MSG msg;

            Hook::hook_handle = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, global::instance_handle, 0);

            while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }

        void stop_hooking () {
            if (Hook::hook_handle != nullptr) {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(this->hook_handle);
                Hook::hook_handle = nullptr;
            }
        }
};

HHOOK Hook::hook_handle = nullptr;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain ([[maybe_unused]] HINSTANCE instance_handle, [[maybe_unused]] DWORD call_reason, [[maybe_unused]] LPVOID reserved) {
    switch (call_reason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            global::instance_handle = instance_handle;
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc ([[maybe_unused]] int n_code, [[maybe_unused]] WPARAM w_param, [[maybe_unused]] LPARAM l_param) {
    std::cout << "KeyboardProc()" << "\n";
    return CallNextHookEx(Hook::get_hook_handle(), n_code, w_param, l_param);
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) Hook_interface *get_hook () {
    return new Hook();
}
```

./Keyboard_hook/index.h

```
#include <Windows.h> // HHOOK

class Hook_interface {
    public:
        virtual void start_hooking () = 0;
        virtual void stop_hooking () = 0;
        virtual ~Hook_interface () = default;
};
```

I built those files like that.

```
cl index.cpp /EHsc /source-charset:utf-8 /std:c++17 /W4 /WX /link /MACHINE:X64 /OUT:a.exe
cl Keyboard_hook/index.cpp user32.lib /EHsc /LD /source-charset:utf-8 /std:c++17 /W4 /WX /link /MACHINE:X64
```

And I executed a `a.exe`, but it only print `KeyboardProc()` messages for 32-bit applications.

but DLL was well injected into 64-bit applications. (I figured out using Process Explorer)
I know that 64-bit DLL doesn't inject to 32-bit applications, So I create a message loop for that.

I'm curious why hook doesn't work for 64-bit applications. When I type keys on 64-bit applications, there's no output. I don't know what I did something wrong. Thanks for reading ! :D

Comment: I think KeyboardProc() function seems to be called well. It just literally injected to other processes, so It didn't print anything on 64-bit App.